# AngularJS: HTML select to use values from map

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have this HTML:

```
<select ng-model="group" ng-options="g.key for g in groups"></select>
```

Although `$scope.groups` is map `{'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':''}`
I'd like select to display map keys: a,b,c

Currently it selects nothing.
How to change `ng-options`?\

**UPDATE 1**

`g for g in Object.keys(groups)` does not work either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
<select ng-model="group" ng-options="key for (key, g) in groups"></select>
```

You can check out the full documentation for the `select` directive, especially the ngOptions details: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: It works, but inclorrectly. For some reason it dislpay unsorted items in `select` and if I try to select any item it just selects the last one and kinda freeze. I had to create another variable $scope.groupKeys = Object.keys($scope.groups) and use it. This way it works